# Reversing a List using an empty list

Tags: python

I wrote a small script to reverse a list, but I always receive an empty one. I know other ways of reversing the list for (e.g) using the slicing notation, but I would like to know what is wrong in my method. Thanks in advance!

Code :

```
def reversing(t):
    temp =[]
    for i in t:
        if i<= len(t)-1:
            hew = t[-1-i]         
            temp.append(hew)
        return temp
reversing([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

Comment: `list(reversed(array))` is what you need. This question has been answered quite often though. Please search before you post a question!

Comment: You're returning *within* the loop. The `if` check basically makes no sense. Probably more…

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `for i in t` means that `i` is an element of `t`, it makes no sense to compare it with `len(t)`.

Comment: It does. Thanks

Comment: The first element `i` is 10.  Since that is greater than 5 (`len(t) - 1`), it's not appended to the list. Then you return `temp` on the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors.

First, I know what you wanted to do in the loop, but the variable i is not what you want. To use the variable i as an index for a list, you should use `range()` with `len()` here.

Secondly, an indentation error. Your code cannot loop due to the location of the `return`.

When you use `for loop` and it doesn work as you expected, easy way to find errors is using `print(i)` inside the loop. Then, you will easily find the gap between what you expected and what the code do.

I fixed your code, as follow:

```
def reversing(t):
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(t)):
        print(i) # This will help you understand how this loop works
        if i <= len(t)-1:
            hew = t[-1-i]
            temp.append(hew)

    return temp


result = reversing([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
print(result)
#[15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10]
```

Comment: @crisbris then you may consider accepting this as the correct answer.